# Nested divs, overflow scroll on the outer one, inner one is truncated

Tags: css, html, overflow

I have some nested `<div>`s. The outer `<div>` has `overflow-x: scroll`, and the inner one has long text (that I don't want to wrap). The problem is that the "inner" `<div>`s don't actually expand into the scrolling area. For example, if I had a `click` event bound to each inner `<div>`, that event wouldn't fire if you scrolled to the right and clicked anywhere over there. In my sample, the red areas are part of the inner `<div>`s and the blue areas aren't (so a click anywhere in the blue areas wouldn't fire).

([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tGkdn/))

Sample HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">one long element right here</div>
    <div class="inner">two long element right here</div>
    <div class="inner">three long element right here</div>
</div>
```

And some simple CSS:

```
.outer {
    width: 15ex;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    background-color: blue;
}

.inner {
    white-space: nowrap;
    background-color: red;
}
```

(colors are for illustrative purposes)

Comment: Actually it looks like events DO fire if you scroll to the right... take a look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/6LSLu/ ... hover works on the right side as well

Comment: Is this what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/tGkdn/3/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I only tried this in Chrome, but it worked:

```
.inner {
    background-color: red;
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: table-row;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tGkdn/5/

I almost just gave you a javascript fix, which I'll post here just in case that is not cross-browser.

```
var inner = document.querySelectorAll('.inner');
for ( var i = 0, l = inner.length; i < l; ++i ) {
    inner[i].style.width = inner[i].parentNode.scrollWidth + 'px';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Obligatory jQuery answer:

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/tGkdn/7/)**

```
$(function () {
    $('.outer').scroll(function () {
        $('.inner').width($('.outer').width() + $('.outer').scrollLeft());
    });

    $('.inner').click(function () {
        $(this).css('background', 'green');
    });
});
```